# Currency (price) formating on custom fields

Tags: custom-field

I need to format a custom field in admin area (post edit) as a currency, eq: 12.000,00 , with user typing only the numbers, the , and . automatic. Ive searched arround, with no sucess.. Anyone? thank

The code i am trying to use to enqueue script in admin is

```
function enqueue_admin() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); //adding Jquery to admin. Not sure if is needed or already there
    wp_register_script( 'autonum', THEME_DIR . '/js/vendor/autoNumeric.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', false ); //this is autoNumeric for currency format
    wp_enqueue_script( 'autonum' );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin' );
```

Also, not sure if i need to change all the $ to JQuery in autoNumeric.js, because of wordpress compatibility

Comment: How are you wanting this to work? Are you talking about dynamic reformatting as the user types?

Comment: yes exactly. I know some jquery plugins like the one simon showed me below, but i am not sucessfully enqueing it in admin area

Comment: Post the code you are trying to use to enqueue the script.

Comment: there's it, in my edit of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to process the field after submitting, php's [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function is what you need:

```
$price = number_format( $number, 2, '.', ',' );
```

but if you want to change how the number is displayed as it's typed in, try [jQuery autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/)

Comment: not really it would be more like a jquery because i need it to format the currency only on admin page while the user insert them and then i need to store the number as INT on the DB so i can sort by custom meta with no problems, thank you

Comment: ah, i understand - i've expanded my answer to include jQuery autoNumeric which hopefully does what you need

Comment: Simon, thats basically what I need, but i'm having some trouble in enqueueing the script on admin area! if you could please please pleeeease help me with that i'd be very gratefull. Note: i'm trully looking for it. I understand I need admin_enqueue_scripts but not sure how to use it in a hook

Comment: it looks like @s_ha_dum has answered this below, it's `THEME_DIR` that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Autonumeric is a jQuery plugin and looks to be written so that you don't have to swap out the `$`.

I think the problem is this line:

```
wp_register_script( 'autonum', THEME_DIR . '/js/vendor/autoNumeric.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', false ); //this is autoNumeric for currency format
```

The problem is that I am not sure where `THEME_DIR` is coming from. That constant is not defined on my test install. I suspect that you have a broken URL for that script.

At any rate, even if `THEME_DIR` is defined and I just missed it, instead of that constant you should probably be using [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) if this is a standalone, or parent, theme or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) if it is a child theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the WordPress function [number_format_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/number_format_i18n/) which use the user locale to format the value.

```
echo number_format_i18n($number, 2)
```

Also, DO NOT USE the PHP [money_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function because it is marked as deprecated in the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better, that you add with a plugin a meta box for your price field. There is easy to filter and format the output. The sore inside the database and it is easier to maintance or add the values inside the field for authors. For read, get output the value can you also use the default functions of custom post type. It give many tutorials and answers on WPSE to this topic.

For the format with **php** it is easy, if you use the [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function.

- A example: `echo money_format('$%i', 3.4); // echos '$3.40'`

I think this function is the right way. The function use the locale var from the WordPress install and and works with different types and languages. A format with the default php functions is not usable for longer time, is the hard way to format in this context.

If you like a way in **javascript**, then see on this [WPSE thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript), very helpfull. But I think, the php way is fast and easy for a output inside a custom field, like in a Meta box.

Comment: thank you for awnser, but my problem is that i can add a meta with INT value, but i need to make it format the currency for the user to see it, and save it as integer

Comment: See my update on this answer. Many languages have a function for this job, also php.